# Is there a way to get the oldest date of a Pandas dataframe when not all columns are dates?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Just to give a little background, I'm trying to loop through the dataframe and query each Asset by it's oldest date. Then I can trim the data with Pandas locally for each of the items that make the asset.

The dataframe that I'm tryin to loop through looks something like this:

[image: Dataframe]

I've tried using query_date = df.min(axis=1) but it picks up the values rather than the dates.

query_date will be the start date for each query that will be inside a for loop.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you share a text based version of your data, we cannot copy and paste a picture to help you.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, not sure if there is a better way than this, if there is please lmk                       :


Index,ASSET_ID,Date1,Value1,Date2,Value2,Date3,Value3,Date4,Value4
0,SQR312,2015-07-16T00:00:00Z,1,2015-07-16T00:00:00Z,0,2014-03-11T00:00:00Z,0,2015-07-16T00:00:00Z,0
1,LSE321,2019-11-11T00:00:00Z,0,2016-08-03T00:00:00Z,0,2019-11-11T00:00:00Z,2,2016-08-03T00:00:00Z,1
2,XYZ444,2019-05-25T00:00:00Z,1,2019-12-20T00:00:00Z,1,2017-03-21T00:00:00Z,0,2016-11-29T00:00:00Z,2
3,PYT319,2019-08-19T00:00:00Z,0,2017-08-14T00:00:00Z,0,2018-09-10T00:00:00Z,0,2018-09-10T00:00:00Z,0

Comment: If your date columns are already in datetime type, I am guessing you want `df.filter(like='Date').min(axis=1)`